# Contact form wordpress, show thank you message on same site (disabel redirect )

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create a contact form for wordpress. 
the form i working good. The problem i have is that, my contact form is in a hidden div.
that slides up when clicking on the mail icon.

so when i send the contact form, it redirect me to a thank you page, i haven't figure out how to disable this function and show the thank you message on the same page.

Any ideas ? I have been reading the other questions but cant seems to help me.
some of the code.

```
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

 <?php if($email){ ?>
     <p><strong>Message succesfully sent. I'll reply as soon as I can</strong></p>
     <?php } else { if($error) { ?>
     <p><strong>Your messange hasn't been sent</strong><p>
     <?php echo $error; ?>
     <?php } else { the_content(); } ?>

             <section class="loginform">
                <div class="contactform">
                <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact_me" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sent" id="sent" value="1" />
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" value="<?php echo $_POST[your_name];?>" placeholder="Name" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" name="your_email" id="your_email" value="<?php echo $_POST[your_email];?>" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" name="your_subject" id="your_subject" value="<?php echo $_POST[your_subject];?>" placeholder="Subject" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <textarea name="your_message" id="your_message"><?php echo stripslashes($_POST[your_message]); ?></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" name = "send" value = "Send email" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </form>
                </section>
     <?php } ?>

     <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can best solve this using ajax; did you build a plugin for this?

You should :)

In your plugin file, register a new ajax hook:

```
// add ajax request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_form', 'sendForm' );
// add this so non-admins can use it
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'sendForm' );
```

Second, build the function sendForm():

```
<?php
function sendForm() {

    //validation logic here, get data from $_POST

    // send mail logic here

    if($email){
        echo '<p><strong>Message succesfully sent. I will reply as soon as I can</strong></p>';
     } else { if($error) { 
         echo '<p><strong>Your messange has not been sent</strong><p>'.$error;
     } else { the_content();

    // adding die(); is necessary with wp ajax
    die();

}
```

In your frontend file, remove all the form stuff or let you input-field return false when it is clicked.
I assume that you are using jQuery in no.Conflict() mode.
Add a `<div id="answer"></div>` where you want the response shown.

```
   <script>
        jQuery('#contact_me input').click( function() {

        // get form data here
        var message = jQuery('#your_message').val();
        // ...and so on

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {   
                    action:     "send_form",
                    message: message,
                    //...and so on

                }, function (response) {

                   jQuery('#answer').html(response);

                }); 
        });
</script>
```

This will call the php-function sendForm() via ajax, execute it and show the echo'ed message in the div with the ID #response. Was it that you needed?

Ask for further explanation.

Regards
Simon

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I'm looking for, will try this after work :)
thanks